# How does taking a real part of a complex matrix change the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ with eigenvalues $(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n)$, is there anything we can say about the eigenvalues of $T = \Re(A)$; let's call them $(\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n)$? Especially, does it hold that $|\lambda_i|\leq|\mu_i|$?

The last part holds for the largest eigenvalue via a norm argument, but I can't really come up with anything for the other eigenvalues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No that is not true in general. Take for example 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -i\\i & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$

This has eigenvalues $0$ and $2$. The real part is just the identity and has repeated eigenvalue 1.

Comment: That's a very good counter-example. Is there anything we can say beside the spectral radius?

Comment: @sarasvati119 Well if your matrix is diagonal, or even just triangular it becomes much easier since your eigenvalues lie on the diagonal (and in this case your conjecture is true). I do wonder perhaps if the smallest $|\lambda_i|$ of the real part must be greater than the smallest $|\mu_j|$ Notice that taking the real part is a linear operation, so you would be hard pressed in general to find specific relations between the eigenvalues.